# codeigniter on wamp 403 forbidden error

Tags: codeigniter, wamp

I set up a codeigniter project on my wamp www folder

The assets of my project is in 'assets' folder which is in the same folder as the application folder.

However when I access my localhost, the css,images and js which are in the asset folder is unable to load.

When I type localhost/assets instead, I can access them.

I set http.conf in the apache folder to set to "Allow from all" as well.

when i access the url from the developer tools for chrome, I have characters within the url like this

> %3C?=%20base_url()%20?%3Eassets/img/a.jpg

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: give your php codes in here

Comment: sure. what code do u need?

Comment: it seems there is something wrong with your view file.

Comment: `<?= base_url() ?>assets/img/a.jpg` is being urlencoded to `%3C?=%20base_url()%20?%3Eassets/img/a.jpg`... Check that you've got [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled on localhost.

Comment: base_url() function is in URL helper. Make sure you are including that.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that the function `base_url()` is not executed and just printed in your view.

Try to **enclose** the function in a php block and echo it out with the path to the asset.

```
<?php 
  echo base_url() . 'assets/img/a.jpg';
?>
```

---

Or as stealthyninja mentioned in the comment, the [short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) you used is interpreted as text.
You can enable it in the `php.ini` with

```
short_open_tag=On
```

When you can't modify the `php.ini`, you can enable it in the codeigniter `config.php` with

```
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = TRUE;
```

Now the **short open tags** are interpreted right

```
<?= base_url() . 'assets/img/a.jpg' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check you config.php file:

```
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = TRUE;
```

or try this :

```
<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/a.jpg
```